A wet spring is killing my 2nd year asparagus plants - can I move them now?
When I planted my asparagus a year ago (drought year), I didn't know that that part of the garden has standing water after heavy rains. This spring has been wet and the plants are turning yellow and the leaves falling off - clearly stressed by too much water.  I want to plant them in a raised bed.  Should I move them now or wait until the plants are dormant in the fall (if they survive)?

Are you planting the aspargus for esthetics or do you want to harvest and eat it?
